# How to minimize an object and build an array from an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and each object has around 5 properties and respective values. I would like to iterate through each object in the array and pick only two properties from it and rebuild the object and the array.

For example:

```
let resArray = [
{"name": "Aaron", "id": 123, "sex": "male", "country": "usa"}, 
{"name": "Bert", "id": 456, "sex": "male", "country": "usa"}, 
{"name": "Brenda", "id": 657, "sex": "female", "country": "canada"}, 
{"name": "Chris", "id": 856, "sex": "male", "country": "usa"}, 
{"name": "Angela", "id": 113, "sex": "female", "country": "columbia"}, 
{"name": "Maria", "id": 569, "sex": "female", "country": "mexico"}];
```

I want to remove the "country" and the "sex" properties from the objects and retain the "name" and "id" properties and rebuild the array. i.e., the output should be as follows:

```
let outArray = [
{"name": "Aaron", "id": 123}, 
{"name": "Bert", "id": 456}, 
{"name": "Brenda", "id": 657}, 
{"name": "Chris", "id": 856}, 
{"name": "Angela", "id": 113}, 
{"name": "Maria", "id": 569}];
```

As of now, I am just using the resArray and iterating through the whole array and getting whatever values I want. But I just think I can minimize the object so that it will be clear of the clutter.

Could anyone help me out with it? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [`object#destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Iterate through your object using `array#map` and get the `name` and `id` value and create a new object.

```js
let resArray = [ {"name": "Aaron", "id": 123, "sex": "male", "country": "usa"}, {"name": "Bert", "id": 456, "sex": "male", "country": "usa"}, {"name": "Brenda", "id": 657, "sex": "female", "country": "canada"}, {"name": "Chris", "id": 856, "sex": "male","country": "usa"}, {"name": "Angela", "id": 113, "sex": "female", "country": "columbia"}, {"name": "Maria", "id": 569, "sex": "female", "country": "mexico"}];
let result = resArray.map(({name, id}) => ({name, id}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you :) Really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and create your desired shape based on the item

```js
let resArray = [
   {"name": "Aaron", "id": 123, "sex": "male", "country": "usa"}, 
   {"name": "Bert", "id": 456, "sex": "male", "country": "usa"}, 
   {"name": "Brenda", "id": 657, "sex": "female", "country": "canada"}, 
   {"name": "Chris", "id": 856, "sex": "male", "country": "usa"}, 
   {"name": "Angela", "id": 113, "sex": "female", "country": "columbia"}, 
   {"name": "Maria", "id": 569, "sex": "female", "country": "mexico"}
];

let mappedArr = resArray.map(item => ({name: item.name, id: item.id}));

console.log(mappedArr);
```

Also you can destruct your parameter `item` inside the parameters list and get only the desired results

```
let mappedArr = resArray.map(({id, name}) => ({name, id}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.map()` as following -

```js
let resArray = [
   {"name": "Aaron", "id": 123, "sex": "male", "country": "usa"}, 
   {"name": "Bert", "id": 456, "sex": "male", "country": "usa"}, 
   {"name": "Brenda", "id": 657, "sex": "female", "country": "canada"}, 
   {"name": "Chris", "id": 856, "sex": "male", "country": "usa"}, 
   {"name": "Angela", "id": 113, "sex": "female", "country": "columbia"}, 
   {"name": "Maria", "id": 569, "sex": "female", "country": "mexico"}
];

let outArray = resArray.map(item => ({name: item.name, id: item.id}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(outArray));
```